# Split string ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, string

I am trying to split string, and i get **ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**

I think i understand, why this error occurs, it happens because there is no value to split right?

Basically i have for loop that returns strings from xml

```
for channel in tree.findall("channel"):
    title = channel.find('title').text
    channelname,tvguide = title.split("[")
    print(channelname,tvguide)
```

When i print out titles i have something like this:

BeIN Sports 1HD [07:00 - 07:30] + 106.8 min   Auto Mundial

BeIN Sports 2HD  **ValueError happens here?**

BeIN Sports 3HD [23:00 - 02:00] + 1216.8 min   Torino FC VS US Citta di Palermo - Italian League ( Serie A )

BeIN Sports 4HD **ValueError happens here?**

BeIN Sports 5HD [05:30 - 07:15] + 91.8 min   Olympique de Marseille VS Angers - French League 1 2015 - 2016 Week 7

My question is, how could i fix for loop so it would split all titles to channelname & tvguide even if some strings dont contain tvguide?

For example in channels that dont have tvguide (in this example BeIN Sports 2HD, BeIN Sports 4HD) it should make tvguide = " " or something similar.

Any ideas guys ?

Comment: Post the data and the traceback.

Comment: Might be able to use `str.partition` instead if more than two `[`'s isn't an errror - eg: `cn, tvg = title.partition('[')[::2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to assigne channelname and tvguide separately, why not take work with the list that the `split` method returns.

```
for channel in tree.findall("channel"):
    title = channel.find('title').text
    description = title.split("[")
    print description
```

This way you need not worry if the channel has a name or tvguide, but make sure you are getting a string in channel object.

`as Jon Clements suggested, we still need to figure out if its allowed to access description[1] and as he suggested an elegant way to do is str.partition`

```
for channel in tree.findall("channel"):
    title = channel.find('title').text
    description = title.partition("[") # you get a tuple with three elements head, separator and tail. 
    #head is the portion before the separator, separator itself and tail the rest of the portion of the string
    print description
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `if else`.

```
x="BeIN Sports 1HD [07:00 - 07:30] + 106.8 min Auto Mundial"

y="BeIN Sports 2H"
ll=[]
ll.append(x)
ll.append(y)
final = [(i,"") if "[" not in i else i.split("[") for i in ll]
print final
```

Output:`[['BeIN Sports 1HD ', '07:00 - 07:30] + 106.8 min Auto Mundial'], ('BeIN Sports 2H', '')]`

Now you can easily process these tuples in the list as per your needs.